# twemproxy(nutcracker), Error: Protocol error, got "{" as reply type byte

Tags: redis, twemproxy

I operated redis through [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy), it can connect to the redis instance, but can't execute any command. No matter what I input, it threw the error

```
 Error: Protocol error, got "{" as reply type byte
```

and then, it exited

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I solved this by myself.

It is because twemproxy will listen on two ports when it starts, one of them is port 22222(by default, you can set it with '-s'), it is used for monitoring, if you connect to it, the error occurs

So, connect to another port